# Can this be proven for any maze?

Tags: puzzle

http://9gag.com/gag/aKgrQDj

Is there a maze that can't be solved simply by following that strategy.

Assumption

1. Solution must exist
2. Sticking your hand to the right or left don't solve that.

Comment: If the goal is in the "center" of the maze, the hand-on-the-wall strategy may not work. (Consider a box in the center of a room. Keeping a hand on a wall of the room will take you round and round and round, but you'll never get to the box.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends a lot on what you consider a maze. If you start in the small room of this

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b5/Maze.svg/800px-Maze.svg.png

you never make it out with either the left or right hand.

It will work both entrance and exit are on the outside of the maze, and there are no bridges or tunnels or other weirdness. To see why the method works, think about the wall your hand is on as having a long path around it. That path must be a loop, and we know that the part of the path on the outside of the maze goes from the exit to the entrance. Therefore, the part on the inside must go from the entrance to the exit, to complete the loop.

Comment: ah....  that makes sense. So the answer is true isn't it.

Comment: Well, it doesn't work for the example that I gave, but for a lot of mazes it will work fine.